# DomCrawler is removing part of the html

Tags: symfony, domcrawler

When I get the content without DomCrawler, I get the html with custom tags like @click but when I use `$this->crawler->filter('something')->html()` DomCrawler is removing my @click tags.

Here an example without using DomCrawler:

[image]

And here is using DomCrawler:

[image]

As you can see, DomCrawler is removing all the @clicks, how can I stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. [DomCrawler](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html) uses [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) under the hood and will not allow the "@click". Also:

> The DomCrawler will attempt to automatically fix your HTML to match the official specification.

The modifiers to disable this would be LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED which is not used in the `addHmlContent` method of DomCrawler:

```
//... Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler.php
$dom->loadHTML($content);
// ...
```

and even calling `@$dom->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);` would not work in your case.

Example:

```
$html = <<<TEST
   <html>
       <div class="test" @click="something"></div>
   </html>
TEST;
    dump($html);
    //<html>\n
    //    <div class="test" @click="something"></div>\n
    //</html>

    // Symfony Crawler
    $crawler = new \Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler();
    $crawler->addHtmlContent($html);
    dump($crawler->html());
    //<body>\n
    //    <div class="test"></div>\n
    //</body>

    // Custom crawler with LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED
    $crawler = new \MyCrawler\Crawler();
    $crawler->addHtmlContent($html);
    dump($crawler->html());
    //  <div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the `@click` with `x-on:click` which has the exact same effect and is valid HTML at the same time.